# splitting a string every 4 characters and then put those into new variables?

Tags: php, string

How would i split a string every 4 characters and then have every 4 characters put into a separate variable so i can do other stuff with each individual 4 characters?

Comment: Tried anything so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, I don't really see you putting each of them in a different variable, because then you'll have like 10 variables:

```
$var1 = ...;
$var2 = ...;
$var3 = ...;
```

But you could use the `str_split` function as following:

`$variable = str_split($origionalvar, 4);`

it will create an array, which you can access:

`$variable[0]` to `$variable[sizeof(variable)]`

If you don't know about arrays, you really should read up on those. They are really great if you want to store a lot of similar information in an object and you don't want to create a new variable for it every time. Also you can loop over them very easily and do some other great stuff with them.

I assume you probably googled this question a bit too. You must have come across http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php. Did you see this page, and if you did, did you have some trouble with it. If so perhaps we can help you reading the documentation properly.

Comment: Not so sure $variable[sizeof(variable)] will work... Should probably be: $variable[sizeof(variable)-1] , I would also recommend not using sizeof, but instead count().

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the `str_split` function. The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) will tell you all you need to know.